# “Core” as the name of a class in school

Tags: meaning, terminology, dialects

When I was in middle school (roughly ages 10–13 years old) in the US in the early 1970s, they combined English—or what might now be called *language arts*—with social studies into a single class that was called *Core*. Even (or particularly?) as adolescents we found the name curious. Nor could we have formulated a decent guess as to why one might have collected what seemed such heterogeneous subject matter into a single class. As far as I have been able to gather, this was a fairly idiosyncratic quirk localized to our county in Maryland, or even just to our school.

Although I would love to know the pedagogical motivation for this practice, that question would be off topic here. So I limit myself to the terminological facets. How widespread (synchronically or diachronically) is/was the label *Core* for such an amalgam of topics and what is/was the thinking behind the choice of label? By the time our kids hit that same middle school (two and a half decades later) it seemed the authorities had come to their senses because that material had been split back apart into two classes with discipline-specific names.

I presume that the name *Core* has to do with someone’s conception of what constitutes the core of the curriculum critical to the formation of young minds, so—roughly speaking—an education school’s dead-earnest analog of *[The Three R’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_three_Rs)*. But that would reflect a greatly impoverished notion of What Kids Today Need To Master compared to, say, the later-arising *[Common Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Core)*.

Comment: "Core", in this sense, was a common term when I was in school (in the Louisville Ky area), back in the 60s.  There was another term, but I'm not recalling it.

Comment: I'm afraid the thinking behind the choice of label is awfully similar to the pedagogical motivation for this practice. Basically, it is the beloved euphemism of bureaucracy.

Comment: It's short for core knowledge. What we used to call the basics.

Comment: I've heard of schools doing this. Usually I think it's because they don't value the humanities much and thus want to minimize the amount of time spent on it by squashing it all into one class.

Comment: @Lambie, as I wrote in my OP, that’s been my presumption. Do you have any supporting sources?

Comment: No, but it's everywhere. core knowledge and core curriculum.

Comment: The use of *core* certainly is quite common. But limited to those two subjects? Someone thought that those two were “more core” than, say, math or science? That’s what I meant by “greatly impoverished notion”: so impoverished as to cast some doubt on the hypothesis.

Comment: This use of the term belongs to the jargon of some educational bureaucracies; I doubt that anybody uses the term this way in ordinary conversations. The answer to the question will thus, as Mr. Baskin has pointed out, be more a matter of reconstructing the operation of these bureaucracies that led them to create the term, than a matter of analysing some spontaneous developments of the language. People at large are, however, often exposed to the term and influenced by it, even if they don't use it much themselves, so the question is still within the scope of this site.

Comment: @alphabet Presumably because STEM is viewed as more important for career prospects, and more useful for society as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to schooling, "core" usually means the main, basic subjects all children must learn, the main two core subjects are English\language arts and math, but sometimes science and social studies are considered core subjects as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You don't seem to be engaging with the question, which discusses a core comprising English and social studies.

Answer (score 0):

"Core" in an educational context, is a reference to a "Core Curriculum", the fundamental concepts that provide the foundations of all subjects to be taught and which often includes civil responsibility.

The earliest reference I can find is "[Curriculum Practices in the Junior High School and Grades 5 and 6"[1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=moBBAAAAIAAJ&q=%22core%20curriculum%22&dq=%22core%20curriculum%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwje8smFhOKEAxXs-QIHHTwfBCsQ6AF6BAgpEAI) by James Madison Glass (pub University of Chicago, 1924) that mentions the concept of a "Core Curriculum"